# Selected Data (Static Select Box) Not appearing when in edit view

Tags: html, css, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Having a problem with a select box in my edit view in (Rails 4 Ruby 2.2) App.

**the select box looks as follows:**

```
 <%= f.select(:primary_type, options_for_select([['RESIDENT - COMPLAINT', 

'RESIDENT - COMPLAINT'], ['THEFT', 'THEFT'], ['PROPERTY DAMAGE', 'PROPERTY 

DAMAGE'], ['DOORS / WINDOWS BROKEN', 'DOORS / WINDOWS BROKEN'], ['WATER LEAKING', 

'WATER LEAKING'], ['FLOODING', 'FLOODING'],['ACCIDENT - PERSONAL INJURY', 

'ACCIDENT - PERSONAL INJURY'], ['ACCIDENT - VEHICLE', 'ACCIDENT - VEHICLE'], 

['ACCIDENT - OTHER', 'ACCIDENT - OTHER'], ['FENCES / GATES BROKEN', 'FENCES / 

GATES BROKEN'], ['SUSPICIOUS ACTIVITY - PERSON', 'SUSPICIOUS ACTIVITY - PERSON'], 

['SUSPICIOUS ACTIVITY - VEHICLE', 'SUSPICIOUS ACTIVITY - VEHICLE'], ['VANDALISM - 

REPORTING', 'VANDALISM - REPORTING'], ['VANDALISM - IN PROGRESS', 'VANDALISM - IN 

PROGRESS'], ['HAZZARD REPORT - SAFETY', 'HAZZARD REPORT - SAFETY'], ['HAZZARD 

REPORT - FIRE', 'HAZZARD REPORT - FIRE'], ['FIRE - ACTIVE', 'FIRE - ACTIVE'], 

['PARKING COMPLAINT - RESIDENT', 'PARKING COMPLAINT - RESIDENT'], ['PARKING 

COMPLAINT - VISITOR', 'PARKING COMPLAINT - VISITOR'], ['BREAK AND ENTER - 

ATTEMPT', 'BREAK AND ENTER - ATTEMPT'], ['BREAK AND ENTER - CONFIRMED', 'BREAK AND 

ENTER - CONFIRMED'], ['ALARM PANEL - PROBLEMS', ' ALARM PANEL - PROBLEMS'], ['GAS 

LEAK', 'GAS LEAK'], ['EXPLOSION', 'EXPLOSION'], ['DAMAGE - WEATHER RELATED', 

'DAMAGE - WEATHER RELATED']]), { include_blank: true }, class: 'input-group input-

group-lg', id: 'primary-box')%>
```

It saves to the DB when selected originally and have confirmed this with Rails Console but have no idea how to get this to display in the select box as the primary value when I go to the edit page.

**my controller is as follows:**

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'ACTIVE'}
    @pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'PENDING'}
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id)
    end
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!And if more info is required please let me know and ill put it up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after reading some other posts and diving a bit deeper into this I found the solution and it seems to be working just great.

```
<%= f.select(:primary_type, options_for_select([['Opt 1', 'Opt 1'],['Opt 2', 'Opt 2']], **:selected => @call.primary_type** )) %>
```

The call that retrieved and displays the Selected value is between the ** ** Do not add the asterisks to your code..

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to set the default you would follow the answer located in the [rails api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

For example:

```
<%= f.select(:primary_type,  options_for_select([["Text1", "value1"],["Text2","value2"] "value2") %>
```

Edit:

On the edit page, you should have a variable set in your controller like `@call = Call.find(params[:id])`

Then in the view you can do:

```
<%= f.select(:primary_type,  options_for_select([<your_values>], @call.primary_type ) %>
```

Comment: No i am asking how to make it appear in the box as the pre selected value when i go to update the form. Right now when i select an item it appears in the show page, when i go to update it re sets the values to to a blank value and if not re selected in the update, clears the values out of the DB

Comment: Can you clarify what the "it" is in that sentence?

Comment: so lets say i want to select "RESIDENT - COMPLAINT", i select it and submit the form.. it saves that value to the DB. When i go to the edit page the select box appears as a blank value, and if i do not re-select "RESIDENT - COMPLAINT" it clears the value from the DB and clears it from the show page ect.

Comment: could this be a result of having {include_blank: true} included in the select box?

Comment: It makes sense however when i try it i get the following error: undefined method `merge' for "PROPERTY DAMAGE":String could this be a result of using a scaffold generated form?

Comment: I found the fix see my answer. Thanks for your assistance.